# onBackPressed and Fragments

Tags: android

**PROBLEM**

I've `MainActivity` with `onBackPressed` overridden that holds `SearchFragment` within and `FrameLayout` for `DetailsFragment`(its an XML for Master/Detail 600dp-land).
Normally the `DetailsFragment` appears in its own `Activity` but on tablets its in `FrameLayout`.

This `DetailsFragment` have additional `View` that is normally hidden but might be shown via user interaction.

What I need is determine first whether `View` must start animating(closing) or leave `Fragment`.

I want to achieve closing this additional `View` before leaving the `DetailsFragment` with `onBackPressed`.

I have no idea how to solve this problem!

Please help me.

Comment: clarify your question please.

Comment: How to communicate between `MainActivity` and `DetailsFragment` in a way that one `onBackPressed` will choose whether to close the `View` or to close `DetailsFragment`.

Comment: when is the time you close the view or fragment

Comment: When `View` is visible I need to close the `View` when its not I need to close the `DetailsFragment`